# How do we balance an FIR around its center?

Tags: signal-processing, dsp, digital-filter, fir

How do we balance an FIR around its center? I was asked this question in an interview. What does this mean? Is the center point the point corresponding to the peak of impulse response?

Comment: Feed the filter design program a constant group delay transfer function, with a delay equal to half the filter length.

Comment: Duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38010669/how-do-we-balance-an-fir-around-its-center

Answer (score 2):

How is a bit of an odd question. Trivially, we can *make* it balanced by making the taps symmetric. This can be done for both odd and even numbers of filter taps, by making it symmetric about the mid sampling time, or half-way between the two mid samples.

More to the point is *why* we should want to do this, and the effect it has on the response. A symmetric FIR filter has a linear phase response, that is, the same delay regardless of frequency. This is a very valuable property in many (but not all) filtering situations.